# How to make map span entire screen MapKit Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Is there a proper way to remove the white space on top of the image, and have the map span the screen from the tab bar upwards? My view controller is quite simple, its just the following. Any help would be appreciated!

```
class MapVC: UIViewController {

    let mapView = MKMapView()
    var window: UIWindow?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        self.view?.addSubview(mapView)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```